# Reading binary files with null bytes in them with C++

Tags: c++, file-io, filestream, binaryfiles, ifstream

What is the canonical way to do this?

I have to do the reading here into a `wstring`, but the answer i'm sure should be applicable to `string` also.

Here's what I am trying now:

```
wifstream file(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
// this next line is cleverer but works the same way (i.e. null byte stops it)
// return wstring(istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>(file), istreambuf_iterator<wchar_t>());
wstring out;
wchar_t buf[8192];
while (true) {
    file.read(buf, 8192);
    streamsize len = file.gcount();                                       
    cerr << len << "chars read.";                                         
    out.append(buf, len);                                                 
    if (len != 8192) break;                                               
}                                                                         
return out;
```

How can I get it to keep reading once it encounters a null byte in the file?

I would actually not have been surprised if POSIX has a decree preventing null bytes from existing in any files ever. But clearly Vim is using some magic to write all those nulls into the undo-file format. Also, nulls must result if you happen to encode or encrypt stuff into a random byte-stream (or many kinds of analog sampling). I mean, I could keep going: the pipes (FIFOs) on OS X handle null bytes going through them just fine: I can cat the undofile, pipe it to xxd, it can read that.

This is obviously some sort of simple thing I'm stumbling over. What is it? Surely there is a C++ way to do it. Or maybe you know a way with `<stdio.h>`. I want to know.

For example, here's the file I'm testing with:

```
% cat .dmp.cpp.un\~| xxd | head                                   
0000000: 5669 6d9f 556e 446f e500 0218 96c6 25f6  Vim.UnDo......%.
0000010: 64bb 2301 6ed8 3578 5c50 61e0 eae5 a819  d.#.n.5x\Pa.....
0000020: b17d 53b5 f932 dc9d 40aa 1b00 0000 8500  .}S..2..@.......
0000030: 0000 5720 2020 2020 2020 2020 2020 2063  ..W            c
0000040: 6572 7220 3c3c 2022 466f 756e 6420 616e  err << "Found an
0000050: 2075 6e70 7269 6e74 6162 6c65 2063 6861   unprintable cha
```

Byte 2b is the first nullbyte. Program reads 44 bytes (2c) so it wrote the first null byte, and stopped there.

```
% la .dmp.cpp.un\~
-rw-r--r--  1 lust  staff  326836 Jul  4 01:41 .dmp.cpp.un~
```

P.S., I got that neat one-liner in the comment from [here](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/353162-reading-a-whole-file-into-a-string-with-ifstream/). Sadly it also suffers from this issue.

Comment: How have you verified that it doesn't? Printing the string will stop at the first `\0`, but the data may still be in the string. Check `std::string::size()` maybe?

Comment: Well, for starters when I run it on my vim undofile, which is many KB, it reads only 44 bytes (I am `cerr`ing what gcount gives me...). I `xxd` the file, and sure enough the 44th byte is a `\0`.

Comment: I have the same with string without any problem:
  while (file.read(buf, sizeof(buf)).gcount() > 0)
    rep.append(buf, file.gcount());

Comment: This code works for me. I suspect is may how you are using the string after it is returned.

Comment: i don't need to do anything with the string!! gcount is a much lower number than the actual real size! If you folks can get it to read past any nullbytes with the same program, please show me a screenshot or something.

Answer (score 0):

I worked around the problem by using a regular string first.

```
ifstream file(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
wstring out;
char buf[8192];
while (true) {
    file.read(buf, 8192);
    streamsize len = file.gcount();
    cerr << len << "chars read.";
    string s(buf, len);
    out.append(s.begin(), s.end());
    if (len != 8192) break;
}
return out;
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause is that `wstring` doesn't hold bytes, but wide characters. Obviously a translation is needed between bytes and (wide) characters. It's this translation which breaks.

If you want to read bytes from a binary file, read them into an appropriate container. E.g. `std::vector<unsigned char>`. If you want to read (wide) characters from a text file, go ahead with your current code. Mixing them is a problem, though.

(This advice holds for many systems, even though they might show problems at different places.  Unix in particular has little distinction between ASCII text files and binary files, whereas Windows tends to have less issues with its Unicode (UTF-16) text files and the in-memory representation thereof.)